# Using Google Analytics v2 without Activity / EasyTracker

Tags: android, google-analytics

When using EasyTracker:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
    }
```

It work great, the problem that i am integrating from older version of analytics and i use it in a service and not in activity, so i cant use activityStart method.

I tried to use:

```
GoogleAnalytics googleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
final Tracker tracker = googleAnalytics.getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-y");
tracker.setStartSession(true);

tracker.sendView("/page");
```

And i dont see anything in the analytics (even after GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch())....

Is there any way to use new version of analytics whitout the activity???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to not use EasyTracker.
It was actually in the oficial site:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced

Basically this what you need to do:
At first initial the tracker like this:

```
// Get the GoogleAnalytics singleton.
mGaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

// Use the GoogleAnalytics singleton to get two Trackers with
// unique property IDs.
mGaTracker = mGaInstance.getTracker("UA-XXXX-Y");
```

Then you can get the tracker like this:

```
mGoogleAnalytics.getDefaultTracker();
```

And use it like:

```
mGoogleAnalytics.sendEvent(.....);

mGaTracker.sendView(....);
```

Comment: What do you send in the event??? what do you send in the View??? what do you see on the analytics page??? can you track it in RealTime?

Comment: @TacB0sS See [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

In a service you need to set the Context before sending a view

Try this:

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
EasyTracker.getTracker().sendView("/page");
```

Comment: I tried it on button click in activity, and it didnt worked for me...
Am i supposed to call activityStart anyway? Can i do it without the activityStart?

Comment: In an activity you call the .activityStart/End with Activity(i.e. context) and then you can call sendView or other functions, in a Service you can't (because you don't have an Activity) so you have to give the EasyTracker the context by calling .setContext before calling other functions.

Comment: Thanks Raanan for your answer, my problem is i dont want to use any method of the analytics that make me use activity, because of code considerations. I solved this in a different way.

Comment: Basically using the setContext lets you use the EasyTracker without an Activity, that was exactly my answer.